# Sitecore with SolrCloud throws HTML tags error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, solrcloud

We recently setup SolrCloud (Solr 4.10.3)  with Sitecore 8.0 Update 2. We have also set it up so that it allows for Switch on Rebuild using this patch - https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.449298/releases.

The setup works fine in one environment but in another environment it is throwing a strange error in the second environment. Some of the indexes rebuild fine but other indexes fail with the following error -

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=Sitecore_web_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: The 'br' start tag on line 1 position 133 does not match the end tag of 'body'. Line 1, position 177.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 group, Int32 groupSize)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.Commit()
   at Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex.Rebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete) in D:\works\projects\gitHubRepo\Sitecore.Support.449298\src\Sitecore.Support.449298\ContentSearch\SolrProvider\SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex.cs:line 155
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

At first look, it looks like the error may be related to some corrupt BR tags without closing slash at the end. But where should I look is not clear.

Also, another issue is that after this happened, the content editor, index rebuild, and other interfaces have started failing with the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the answer to your batch update from the Solr server is incorrect. It might be related e.g. to max request length or some missing languages in the Solr configuration. Try either to login to Solr server admin and see if there are any errors of use Fiddler to check what are the responses from Solr when index rebuild fails.

Comment: Where can i find the max request length setting?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/472026/199203

Comment: Ok, I can try that. Do you think it may be caused by the Load Balancer in front of the Solr nodes?

Comment: It was the Load Balancer causing the issue. Made some configuration changes to it and it just worked. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Gabbar for the benefit of other visitors can you please explain how the load balancer caused this issue and what you did to fix it.  Make it an answer and I'll upvote you.